# Is it possible to clone html element objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html element (like select box input field) in a table. Now I want to copy the object and generate a new one out of the copy, and that with JavaScript or jQuery. I think this should work somehow but I'm a little bit clueless at the moment.

Something like this (pseudo code):

```
oldDdl = $("#ddl_1").get(); 

newDdl = oldDdl;

oldDdl.attr('id', newId);

oldDdl.html();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+copy+element+content has a bunch of related questions.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Using your code you can do something like this in plain JavaScript using the [cloneNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) method:

```
// Create a clone of element with id ddl_1:
let clone = document.querySelector('#ddl_1').cloneNode( true );

// Change the id attribute of the newly created element:
clone.setAttribute( 'id', newId );

// Append the newly created element on element p 
document.querySelector('p').appendChild( clone );
```

Or using jQuery [clone()](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/clone) method (not the most efficient):

```
$('#ddl_1').clone().attr('id', newId).appendTo('p'); // append to where you want
```

Comment: It is VERY important to modify the ID when you clone an element.

Answer (score 359):

The modern approach is to use the [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) function:

```
let new_element = element.cloneNode(true);
```

where the Boolean indicates whether to also clone its child nodes or not.

Afterwards, you can add the cloned element to DOM somewhere. For example, you can use [`after()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/after) to insert the new element right after the original element:

```
element.after(new_element);
```

**Compatibility:**

[Browser compatibility for Element.after](https://caniuse.com/?search=after)

[Browser compatibility for Node.cloneNode](https://caniuse.com/?search=cloneNode)

Comment: best answer. don´t use jquery where you don´t need it.

Comment: Looks good ... but browser compatibility is questionable as of today.

Comment: @AniketSuryavanshi I'm not sure about February 4th in particular, but [compatibility looks perfect today](http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/#t91)

Comment: IDs and names will be duplicated. IDs NEED to be changed, names COULD be left as they are if duplicate names are expected.

Comment: Too bad you lose all attributes :/

Comment: This doesn't seem to clone `on*` handlers, so you'll need to do something like `new_element.onclick = element.onclick`

Answer (score 17):

Yes, you can copy children of one element and paste them into the other element:

```
var foo1 = jQuery('#foo1');
var foo2 = jQuery('#foo2');

foo1.html(foo2.children().clone());
```

Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/de9kc/

Comment: Duplicate IDs will be an issue with Your approach

Answer (score 4):

Get the HTML of the element to clone with `.innerHTML`, and then just make a new object by means of `createElement()`...

```
var html = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML;
var clone = document.createElement('span');
clone.innerHTML = html;
```

In general, *clone() functions must be coded by, or understood by, the cloner*.  For example, let's clone this: `<div>Hello, <span>name!</span></div>`.  If I delete the clone's `<span>` tags, should it also delete the original's span tags?  If both are deleted, the object references were cloned; if only one set is deleted, the object references are brand-new instantiations.  In some cases you want one, in others the other.

In HTML, typically, you'll want anything cloned to be referentially self-contained.  The best way to make sure these new references are contained properly is to have the same innerHTML rerun and re-understood by the browser within a new element.  Better than working to solve your problem, you should know exactly how it's doing its cloning...

**Full Working Demo:**

```js
function cloneElement() {
    var html = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML;
    var clone = document.createElement('span');
    clone.innerHTML = html;
    document.getElementById('clones').appendChild(clone);
}
```

```html
<span id="test">Hello!!!</span><br><br>

<span id="clones"></span><br><br>

<input type="button" onclick="cloneElement();" value="Click Here to Clone an Element">
```

Answer (score 3):

It's actually very easy in jQuery:

```
$("#ddl_1").clone().attr("id",newId).appendTo("body");
```

Change .appendTo() of course...

Answer (score 3):

You can use **clone()** method to create a copy..

```
$('#foo1').html( $('#foo2 > div').clone())​;
```

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/dYUUC/)

Answer (score 3):

Vanilla JS approach on what you are trying to do

```
const oldDdl = document.querySelector('#ddl_1');

const newDdl = oldDdl.cloneNode(true);

oldDdl.setAttribute('id','newId');

const oldDdlHtml = oldDdl.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#foo1').html($('#foo2').children().clone());
```

Answer (score 0):

In one line:

```
$('#selector').clone().attr('id','newid').appendTo('#newPlace');
```

Comment: I don't think that will help as your attribute value is a string that won't change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select "#foo2" as your selector. Then, get it with html().

Here is the html:

```
<div id="foo1">

</div>
<div id="foo2">
    <div>Foo Here</div>
</div>​
```

Here is the javascript:

```
$("#foo2").click(function() {
    //alert("clicked");
    var value=$(this).html();
    $("#foo1").html(value);
});​
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fritzdenim/DhCjf/