# Dynamically display/add the same form to the page with different fields

Tags: javascript, jsp

How will my `index.jsp` look like if a button `Add more` is added next to the `Process` button, which when pressed will display another search form identical to the previous (as displayed below) but with different parameter or field like `age`, `year` etc. Example: `<!-- how will I change the cloned form instead of displaying Car reg: <input type="text" name="car" /> to show  age: <input type="text" name="age" />  -->`  `<!-- how will I change the cloned form instead of displaying  <input type="button"

        onClick="addMoreForm('age')" value="Add More" /> to show <input type="button" 
        onClick="delete('age')" value="delete" />  -->
         </div>`

Comment: What are you doing and what do you want from us? Can you make your question a little more simplified? Thanks

Comment: In my jsp, I have a form made of field name "Car reg", user input field "car", dropdownlist "color" and submit button "Process". I would like to add a button next to the submit "Process" call "add more". Onclick of "add more" it will duplicate the same form under the previous one with different field name eg " instead of Car reg field as shown in the code, it will be age or year. thanks

Comment: You can do this with the help of javascript (or with some good javascript libraries like jQuery or YUI) adding fields to the same form and adding a different form below this form. This approach has nothing to do with `JSP` just javsacript will do. On the otherhand do you want that onClick of `Add more` you will hit the server and this JSP will be refreshed and will show two forms and then if clicked again it will refresh and show 3 forms ...? Hope I am not confusing you ;-)

Comment: I would appreciate if you provide the code for adding a completely new form with different fields (like age, year etc) when a button "add more" is clicked in the same jsp. same form with different field name below each other whenever `add more` is clicked. I am building a java web app using jsp-servlet, the above code is actually in my jsp.  onClick of `Add more` I will get a similar form to the previous with different field name like age, onclick of `add more` in the second form show third form. :) thanks

Comment: Actually I would have loved to make the code for you, but then people on this site say "First ask to the questioner - `what have you tried?`, `what code is not working?`, `show some code which you tried?` this shows that the questioner wants to learn and is not some help-vampire (http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19665/186393). So I would request you to post some code which you have tried to achieve this. For a start plz answer: 1) do you want to do this in javascript or by hitting the server everytime you say `Add More`? 2)  What is your requirement in doing this? 3) do you know javascript?

Comment: Hi friend, the code shown above is what i have done to display one form. JSP is made of html and javascript, you can't build a java web app without any knowledge of javascript. if you can put your answer in code as i did in my question that will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Great! Nice to hear that. Can you tell me what javascript code have you tried to add another form or which is adding anything on the page? Thanks.

Comment: "Can you tell me what javascript code have you tried to add another form or which is adding anything on the page?" none. thanks

Comment: :-) anyways I have tried to give an answer

Answer (score 0):

This might get you started ...

You can create a button or an anchor `<a>` link (whichever you like) for calling the function:

```
<input type="button" onClick="addMoreForm('the parameters come here*')" value="Add More" />
```

- The `parameters` to the `addMoreForm` method might be like: formName, fieldName, fieldType, formAction, formMethod etc **to create a form through javascript**, here are some links for creating elements in javascript (`<form>` is an element :-) ):
- http://www.dustindiaz.com/add-and-remove-html-elements-dynamically-with-javascript/
- With jQuery: [jQuery document.createElement equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268490/jquery-document-createelement-equivalent/268520#268520)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/327068/468763
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/867981/468763

**or**

- you can pass the `formName` and `formId` of the form to be copied, again some links:
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/921302/468763
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/710347/468763
- an example with **cloning** with pure javacript, I am cloning your `form1` to create a `form2` where `addingMoreId` is a container like a `<div>` tag where your `form2` will be created:

  ```
  var form2 = document.getElementById("form1").cloneNode(true);
  form2.setAttribute("name", "form2");
  form2.setAttribute("id", "form2");
  document.getElementById("addingMoreId").appendChild(form2);
  ```

**P.S.:** For crowse-browser compatibility you can use a javascript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/).

**Edit:** Here is a sample code, you can improve a lot in this code and also can make it more generic.

```
<input type="button" onClick="addMoreForm('age')" value="Add More" />

<div id="addingMoreId">
    <!-- This is empty, the form2 will be created here -->
    <!-- So it is not required that the form be present here -->
</div>

<!-- This script tag goes into the <head> tag -->
<script>
    // this function will create the form2 in the div
    // you agree or not, you need to learn a lot more about Javascript :-)
    function addMoreForm(fieldName) {
        var form2 = document.getElementById("form1").cloneNode(true);
        form2.setAttribute("name", "form2");
        form2.setAttribute("id", "form2");
        document.getElementById("addingMoreId").appendChild(form2);
        form2.car.setAttribute("name", fieldName); // one way to access the element inside a form: "form2.car", where "car" is the name of the element created inside the form2
        form2.elements[fieldName].setAttribute("id", fieldName); // another way to access the element inside a form: "form2.elements["car"]"
    }
</script>
```

Lets Hope this helps :-)

Comment: No. it is `<form id="form1" name="form1" action="someAction" method="GET"> ... </form>` and `<form id="form2" name="form2" action="someAction" method="GET"> ... </form>`, Age and year are elements/fields inside this form. You can either create these elements (I have given links how to create Elements) or change the `<select name="color">` to `<select name="age">` or `<select name="year">` by fetching the `select` element from `var form2` and then using `.setAttribute("name", "age")`.

Comment: I have edited my code to include your solution, still does not work. would you like to edit it to reflect what you mean for it to work?  thanks

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a sample code. You need to put your javascript inside a `<script>` tag, so now my friend I guess you were being a little silly `:-p`. The second `form` need not be there, just the `div` as shown. Hope this helps `:-)`

Comment: thanks @Prakash :) , it works for the cloning but it does not : ` <!-- how will I change the cloned form instead of displaying Car reg: <input type="text" 
     name="car" /> to show  age: <input type="text" name="age" />  -->

   <!-- how will I change the cloned form instead of displaying  <input type="button"  
    onClick="addMoreForm('age')" value="Add More" /> to show <input type="button" 
    onClick="delete('age')" value="delete" />  -->`

Comment: I have already given code for changing the `name=car` to `name=age` and for changing the `onClick` for the `button` it is better to create one instead of changing it. Though in `jQuery` it would be very easy. I have already posted links to create elements. Thanks