# How to 'duplicate' element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to clone html element objects in JavaScript / JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921290/is-it-possible-to-clone-html-element-objects-in-javascript-jquery)

For example, I want this:

```
<div id="foo1">

</div>
<div id="foo2">
  <div>Foo Here</div>
</div>
```

To become this:

```
<div id="foo1">
  <div>Foo Here</div>
</div>
<div id="foo2">
  <div>Foo Here</div>
</div>
```

Is this possible with jQuery?

Comment: I thought this was duplicate "on click" question...