# Duplicate an element?

Tags: css

I'm trying to duplicate an element in a page. I do not exactly how, is it possible with CSS or I need to use a script?

I imagine something like this:

```
  #yan:before { 
    content: Get The Value Of(AN.element.inPage) !important;
    font-size: 200% !important;
    }
```

E.G.:
  Let's say I want to get the title of a topic.

```
  #yan:before { 
    content: Get The Value Of(h1.subject) !important;
    font-size: 200% !important;
    }
```

Then the topic title would appear 2 times in the page. Is it possible?

NOW This is my RIGHT code...

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        DUPLICATING - CLONE elements
// @namespace   http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/109262
// @description    EXPLAIN ME PLEASE
// @include     http*://*answers.yahoo.com*
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==


var yan = document.getElementById('yan'),
h1s = document.querySelectorAll('h1.subject');

[].forEach.call(h1s, function(node) {
// insert before
yan.parentNode.insertBefore(node.cloneNode(true), yan);
});
```

►►►► BUT now how do I set a position relative to the "#yan-related" element??
►►►► I want the newly created element to follow the #yan-related.

Answer (score 5):

This is only possible with script, e.g.

```
var yan = document.getElementById('yan'),
h1s = document.querySelectorAll('h1.subject');

[].forEach.call(h1s, function(node) {
    // insert before
    yan.parentNode.insertBefore(node.cloneNode(true), yan);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/evicov/1/)

Comment: @user742625 I don't know what `#yan-related` is.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use jquery. Check `clone()`

```
var a = $("#dashnav").clone
$("#dashnav").after(a)
```

Comment: I'm new in this, could you write an example and tell me where can I insert it? in wich file, I use GreaseMonkey and Stylish.

Comment: Suppose you have an element and you want to duplicate and insert it after the first element. Edited the answer for it.

Answer (score 0):

No, CSS is for layout purposes, and cannot clone HTML elements. You will have to use JavaScript/jQuery for this purpose.

See related question on how to use `.clone()`:

[Is it possible to clone html element objects in JavaScript / JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921290/is-it-possible-to-clone-html-element-objects-in-javascript-jquery)

Comment: All things considered, this should be a comment.