# saving html element to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

This JS tries to save a html element to `myHTML`. but later when that element changes, the variable also changes.
How can I save a copy of `myHTML` to use it later?

```js
let myHTML = '';
$('td.label').each(function() {
  if (this.textContent === "sign:") {
    if (!myHTML) myHTML = this.parentElement;
    return false;
  }
});

//later the elemnt gets changed
$('td.label').each(function() {
  if (this.textContent === "sign:") {
    this.parentElement.appendChild(some-html-element)
    return false;
  }
});

console.log(myHTML);  //it includes the some-html-element
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921290/is-it-possible-to-clone-html-element-objects-in-javascript-jquery

Comment: Not always, @N.J.Dawson https://jsfiddle.net/z481LL1z/1/

Comment: Do you need the whole html object there? If not then you can use the html string. myHTML = this.parentElement.html()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [the `cloneNode()` method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_clonenode.asp) to set `myHTML` to a *copy* of the element:

`myHTML = this.parentElement.cloneNode();`

Comment: it will not clone the rest of the tree which is not what I want. I want to clone the whole tree

Answer (score 0):

I think because it is an object, js will reference it, and on change even your `myHTML` object changes too. This approach below should work correct, because it is not using DOM objects directly.

```
var myHTML;

$('td.label').each(function() {
    if( $(this).text() === "sign:" ) {
        if( !myHTML ) {
            myHTML = $(this).parent();
        }

        return false;
    }
});

$('td.label').each(function() {
    if( $(this).text() === "sign:" ) {
        $(this).parent().append("some-html-element");
        return false;
    }
});

console.log(myHTML);
```