# How to append multiple elements to a div using DocumentFragment

Tags: javascript, html

```
function JGallery() {
    this.elements = this._init();
    this.overlay = this.elements.overlay;
    this.media_hld = this.elements.media_hld;
}


JGallery.prototype._init = function(){
    var overlay = document.createElement('div');
    var media_hld = document.createElement('div');

    return{
        'overlay': overlay,
        'media_hld': media_hld
    }
};
```

This is where I create a document fragment and using it so I can add several div to same element:

```
JGallery.prototype.getReference = function(holder) {
    var overlay = this.overlay;
    var media_hld = this.media_hld;
    var that = this;
    var holderChildren = holder.querySelectorAll('img');
    var docfrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    holderChildren.forEach(function (e) {
        e.addEventListener('click', JGallery.prototype.showMe.bind(that), false);
        var media_holder = that.media_hld;
        media_holder.textContent = "<img src="+e.getAttribute('src')+">";
        docfrag.appendChild(media_holder);
//it only appends the last child of my array...
    });
    overlay.appendChild(docfrag);
};
```

my goal is to have something like this:

```
<div class="JGallery_BG">
  <div class="JGallery_mediaContainer"><img src="images/thumb_video.jpg"></div>
  <div class="JGallery_mediaContainer"><img src="images/thumb_video.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

by the way the `forEach` function works well, 8 or 9 times. But I'm not sure whether it adds node to `docFrag` on every run or not.

Another thing, I'm not insisting to use a document fragment, if there is a better way to add multiple elements to one element, I like to know about it and use it.

Comment: You need to clone your `that.media_hld` element if you want to add multiple instances. Right now, you're overwriting the `textContent` of that single `div` every time, and only appending that single instance. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/921316/215552

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problems is that you are constantly re-using the same media holder `<div>` element in every iterations.

In the code below `that.media_hld` is always referencing the same element.

```
var media_holder = that.media_hld;
media_holder.textContent = "<img src="+e.getAttribute('src')+">";
docfrag.appendChild(media_holder);
```

If you clone the node it should work and you also need to set the `innerHTML` property, not the `textContent`.

```
var media_holder = that.media_hld.cloneNode();
```

One other thing I did spot is that what's returned from `querySelectorAll` is not an array and thus doesn't have a `forEach` method.

You could borrow `forEach` from an array instance though:

```
[].forEach.call(holderChildren, forEachBodyFunction);
```

The entire thing could read:

```
JGallery.prototype.getReference = function(holder) {
    var docfrag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        images = holder.querySelectorAll('img');

    [].forEach.call(images, function (img) {
        img.addEventListener('click', JGallery.prototype.showMe.bind(this), false);
        var media_holder = this.media_hld.cloneNode();
        media_holder.appendChild(img.cloneNode());
        docfrag.appendChild(media_holder);

    }.bind(this));

    this.overlay.appendChild(docfrag);
};
```