# Why can't I set the id of my node clone when using the cloneNode method in js?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to create a clone of a div Element with the method cloneNode and then I want to set the id of the clone with the setAttribute method, but I get this error:

*Property 'setAttribute' does not exist on type 'Node'.*

[image]

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="containerParentId" class="row boundary">

<div class="col no-padding" id="containerId" 
(drop)="onDrop($event)" 
(dragover)="onDragOver($event)" 
(dragleave)="onLeave($event)">

    <div class="vl" id="verticalLine" ></div>

    <div id="divTable" class="tableOnePosition"
    draggable="true"
    (dragstart)="onDragStart($event)"
    (drag)="onDrag($event)"
    (dragend)="onDragEnd($event)"

    ></div>
</div>
```

And here is the js code:

```
let clone = document.getElementById('divTable').cloneNode(true);

clone.setAttribute('id','newId');
```

I'm using Angular as my frontend framework.

I have read different questions about this and it should be possible as far as I can see. An example is this question: [Is it possible to clone html element objects in JavaScript / JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921290/is-it-possible-to-clone-html-element-objects-in-javascript-jquery)

Comment: [`.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) returns a [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node). [`.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) is a method of [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element). And that's what TypeScript is trying to tell you.

Comment: What would be the best solution to fix the problem then?

Answer (score 3):

[`.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) returns a [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) but [`.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) is only available on [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)s (or derived types of it). And that's what TypeScript tells you with the warning/error.

You have to tell TypeScript that the node returned by `.cloneNode()` is actually a `Element`/`HTMLElement`/`HTMLDivElement`. To do so TypeScript knows the concept of [Type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) (which is like a type cast in other languages).

There are two forms to specify a type:

1. `< Type >` -> `const d = <HTMLDivElement> document.querySelector("div")`
2. `as` -> `const d = document.querySelector("div") as HTMLDivElement`

Your script would then look like:

```
const clone = <HTMLDivElement> document.getElementById('divTable').cloneNode(true);
```

or

```
const clone = document.getElementById('divTable').cloneNode(true) as HTMLDivElement;
```

Example in the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJjAvPEwCuBbApmKA6YAJywEMosBRAGy21wAoAiOASwDdGBKAbgChfQkWMCrgsSeAVFgsAORBws9KITRZOMEhBgAJACoBZADIARdtVo4ofEWLwQsUAIJQVLAEZpyTFnEYAaGEYAMxAQLm4gA)